# In a polygon network, how can a contract be verified programmatically? Could api verification be supported like in Binance or HECO?

Tags: contract-development, polygon

It is only way to verify contracts using UI on their site but it is a long process.

Comment: Matic devs said me in discord there is no way to do this. The only way is to use site((((((